How do I get CDB to show source lines for Microsoft’s C++ Standard Library?
I’m working on contributing to Descent 3. The pull request that I’m currently working on has a Windows-only bug. I would like to use a debugger in order to help me track down the bug.
Specifically, the abort() function gets called when you try to open the Multiplayer menu. I was able to use CDB to get a backtrace for the crash:
0:000:x86> kp
ChildEBP RetAddr
0075e080 71b11701     ucrtbased!issue_debug_notification(wchar_t * message = 0x71a7384c "abort() has been called")+0x30 [minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\internal\report_runtime_error.cpp @ 28]
0075e098 71b23eba     ucrtbased!__acrt_report_runtime_error(wchar_t * message = 0x71a7384c "abort() has been called")+0x11 [minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\internal\report_runtime_error.cpp @ 154]
0075e0a8 00da135d     ucrtbased!abort(void)+0x1a [minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\startup\abort.cpp @ 51]
0075e0b0 00b89e89     Descent3!__std_fs_directory_iterator_close(__std_fs_dir_handle _Handle = 0n34772936 (No matching enumerant))+0x1d [D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\github\stl\src\filesystem.cpp @ 255]
0075e0c0 00b89e49     Descent3!std::filesystem::_Find_file_handle::~_Find_file_handle(void)+0x19 [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\filesystem @ 611]
0075e0cc 00b8a3e6     Descent3!std::filesystem::_Dir_enum_impl::~_Dir_enum_impl(void)+0x19
0075e0d8 00b87d5d     Descent3!std::filesystem::_Dir_enum_impl::`scalar deleting destructor'(void)+0x16
0075e0e4 00b8a96a     Descent3!std::_Destroy_in_place<std::filesystem::_Dir_enum_impl>(struct std::filesystem::_Dir_enum_impl * _Obj = 0x136a6110)+0xd [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xmemory @ 293]
0075e0f4 00b8a83d     Descent3!std::_Ref_count_obj2<std::filesystem::_Dir_enum_impl>::_Destroy(void)+0x1a [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\memory @ 2101]
0075e104 00b8a7f2     Descent3!std::_Ref_count_base::_Decref(void)+0x2d [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\memory @ 1163]
0075e110 00b89da6     Descent3!std::_Ptr_base<std::filesystem::_Dir_enum_impl>::_Decref(void)+0x22 [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\memory @ 1380]
0075e11c 00b89f16     Descent3!std::shared_ptr<std::filesystem::_Dir_enum_impl>::~shared_ptr<std::filesystem::_Dir_enum_impl>(void)+0x16 [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\memory @ 1671]
0075e128 00b7ed01     Descent3!std::filesystem::directory_iterator::~directory_iterator(void)+0x16 [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\filesystem @ 2700]
0075eab8 00b20216     Descent3!MainMultiplayerMenu(void)+0x7c1 [D:\VC\Partially mine\Descent3\repo\Descent3\multi_ui.cpp @ 457]
0075f578 00a7d8e6     Descent3!MainMenu(void)+0x626 [D:\VC\Partially mine\Descent3\repo\Descent3\menu.cpp @ 876]
0075f598 00a7d754     Descent3!MainLoop(void)+0x86 [D:\VC\Partially mine\Descent3\repo\Descent3\descent.cpp @ 543]
0075f654 00c82f13     Descent3!Descent3(void)+0x214 [D:\VC\Partially mine\Descent3\repo\Descent3\descent.cpp @ 507]
0075f660 00c825d1     Descent3!oeD3Win32App::run(void)+0x13 [D:\VC\Partially mine\Descent3\repo\Descent3\winmain.cpp @ 145]
0075f7cc 00c81a7b     Descent3!HandledWinMain(struct HINSTANCE__ * hInst = 0x009e0000, struct HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInst = 0x00000000, char * szCmdLine = 0x0203136e "-WINDOWED -NOINTRO -PILOT JAYMAN2000", int nCmdShow = 0n10)+0x271 [D:\VC\Partially mine\Descent3\repo\Descent3\winmain.cpp @ 525]
0075f818 00dbaf7d     Descent3!WinMain(struct HINSTANCE__ * hInst = 0x009e0000, struct HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInst = 0x00000000, char * szCmdLine = 0x0203136e "-WINDOWED -NOINTRO -PILOT JAYMAN2000", int nCmdShow = 0n10)+0x6b [D:\VC\Partially mine\Descent3\repo\Descent3\winmain.cpp @ 536]
0075f838 00dbadfa     Descent3!invoke_main(void)+0x2d [D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl @ 107]
0075f894 00dbac8d     Descent3!__scrt_common_main_seh(void)+0x15a [D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl @ 288]
0075f89c 00dbaff8     Descent3!__scrt_common_main(void)+0xd [D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl @ 331]
0075f8a4 760d7ba9     Descent3!WinMainCRTStartup(void * __formal = 0x004e0000)+0x8 [D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_winmain.cpp @ 17]
0075f8b4 779dc10b     KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x19
0075f90c 779dc08f     ntdll32!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2b
0075f91c 00000000     ntdll32!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
0:000:x86> 

I wanted to know why __std_fs_directory_iterator_close() was calling abort(), so I tried setting a breakpoint on __std_fs_directory_iterator_close():
0:011> bp __std_fs_directory_iterator_close
0:011> g
[…]
Entering MainMultiplayerMenu()
Breakpoint 0 hit
Descent3!__std_fs_directory_iterator_close:
00da1340 55              push    ebp
0:000:x86> 

I always use CDB in source debugging mode (I run CDB with these command-line arguments: -lines -c "ld Descent3; l+s; l+t" -o "%cd%\Descent3.exe".), but it’s not showing the source lines for __std_fs_directory_iterator_close(). CDB shows source lines for functions that are in Descent 3’s source code, but it doesn’t show source lines for functions that are in the C++ standard library.
How do I get CDB to show source lines for STL (Microsoft’s C++ Standard Library)?

You can get CDB to show source lines for STL (Microsoft’s C++ Standard Library) by downloading a copy of the STL repository and setting CDB’s source path:

Make sure that Git is installed:
winget install Git.Git


Restart your Command Prompt in order to make sure that Git is on your Path.

Clone the STL repository:
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/STL


(Optional) Make sure that the Git repo and your code are using the same version of STL:

Change directory into the STL repo:
CD STL


Determine the appropriate Git tag. I’m using Visual Studio 2022 version 17.10.2, so the appropriate tag for me is vs-2022-17.10. You can find a list of Git tags for the STL repo here.

Switch to the tag:
git switch --detach <tag>




Start CDB:
<path-to-cdb> -lines -c "l+t; l+s; .srcfix; .srcpath+ <path-to-STL-repo>" -o <path-to-debugee>

Note: Don’t escape <path-to-STL-repo>, even if it contains spaces.



Are these esoteric things, are we just going to see the documentation reproduced on SO over the next few months?

Upvoting on trust, this sounds useful

@sweenish I don’t know if they’re esoteric or not. I just know that these are the things that I’ve struggled with as a new CDB user. I wouldn’t say that I’m reproducing the documentation. The documentation lacks noob-friendly tutorials for many of the things that I want to do. I end up having to combine information from multiple different pages in order to accomplish a single task, and it takes me a while to find the right pages.

@sweenish CDB is just like GDB or LLDB, how can it be esoteric? The interface and stable features aren't going to be extinct. It'll die when no body use MSVC or GDB/LLDB anymore

@phuclv You’re missing the point of my question. And given how much time has passed, I’m not really invested anymore.
